# Alibaba Cloud - Taking a SnapShot/Image on Free trial

Tags: snapshot, alibaba-cloud, alibaba-cloud-ecs

I am trying the Alibaba Cloud, ECS instances and after doing some configuration I would like to persist that so that if I want to rollback the Instance after certain period I can start from the last checkpoint. What I want to understand is if Taking a SnapShot/Image on Free trial would cost me money ? or in other words if I create an image or snapshot would that be chargeable, if yes then how much would it cost to me for each snap shot or image?

Best Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the mentioned terms while creating image -

- > When you create an image, a snapshot will be created as well. Because
  >   the snapshot service is now a paid service, your images will incur
  >   snapshot fees.
- > When creating a custom image with Linux system, please
  >   do not load data disk information in the /etc/fstab file. Otherwise,
  >   you cannot launch the instance created through the image.
- > You can create a complete image template for the current ECS instance,
  >   including all its disks. A new snapshot will be taken for each
  >   instance disk and can be viewed in the snapshot list. You must wait
  >   for the snapshots for each disk to be created before the image can be
  >   used. Please be patient.

So yes taking snap shot or creating image has cost associated with it, how much cost is dependent on how much resources has been associated with it. Please refer to below screenshot for the reference -

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As per the [official documentation](https://www.alibabacloud.com/help/doc-detail/25391.htm?spm=a2c63.p38356.b99.36.72762fabVP0zmi), snapshots service is free of charge. You can reaffirm this with the following figure of their documentation.

[image]